# Doxygen: How to hide certain page in treeview

Tags: treeview, hide, doxygen

I have an issue I could not resolve by myself. Help please.

I have (conditionally):

```
/** @mainpage A
@subpage B
*/

/** @page B 
@subpage C
*/

/** @page C */
```

Doxygen makes the tree where all the pages are shown on the root level.

+A/
|---B/
|------C
|---B   <- WANT TO HIDE
|---C   <- WANT TO HIDE

but I need only top (A here and nested B & C) to be visible i.e. should be organized accordingly @subpage tags.

I also tried to set visible to 'no'
 
in DoxygenLayout.xml. But it hides all the pages, only 'files' and 'classes'
are left.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your code generates the required tree view (only nested pages without separate entries at the root level) when the page/subpage files belong to most of the supported formats like `*.c`, `*.cpp`, `*.dox` etc. The only exception that I could find (in Doxygen 1.8.6) is the markdown format (`*.md` or `*.markdown`), for which separate root level entries are generated as well.

Until markdown files are [treated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502426/how-to-make-an-introduction-page-with-doxygen/9522667#comment12326185_9522667) like the other file formats, a workaround would be to use one of the other file formats (like `*.dox`) instead of `*.md` for the pages/subpages. Currently, the markdown format can be used, without generating root level entries, only for the [mainpage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13442157/4128146).

Comment: In short, each `*.md` file generates a page at root level inevitably. (For me it's version 1.9.1)

Comment: Try v1.9.6, it solves this.